# Change user during execution of csh script using non root user

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I am logged on as user JSmith. 
As this user, I run a csh script which runs a series of executables.
However, one of these executables needs to be run with the user HJones.
After that, the other executables should be run with user JSmith.
Note that JSmith is not the root user and that HJones has a password, which is "abcd".
How do I change the user to HJones during the run of the script, run my executable, and then change back to JSmith.

Here's some code in the file run_execs.sh, which I run with user JSmith.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

cd $EXEC_DIRECTORY

./doJSmithThis
./doJSmithThat

sudo -u HJones ??

./doHJonesStuff

sudo -u JSmith ??

./doJSmithAnother
./doJSmithMoreStuff
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

`su -c './doHJonesStuff' - HJones` will run the script `doHJonesStuff` as `HJones`, it will not affect your other commands.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

cd $EXEC_DIRECTORY

./doJSmithThis
./doJSmithThat

su -c './doHJonesStuff' - HJones

./doJSmithAnother
./doJSmithMoreStuff
```

Comment: HJones is password protected, so how do I pass the password in ? JSmith is not a root user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the csh script to supply the password:

```
( sleep 1 ; echo abcd ) | socat -,ignoreeof EXEC:'su -c ./doHJonesStuff HJones',pty
```

(The `sleep 1` is there because `su` would discard a password that arrived before the prompt.)